# Mule FunctionalTestComponent event callbacks - event is never received

Tags: mule

I am trying to use the `FunctionalTestComponent` to catch messages in Mule so I can assert against certain Header properties mid flow. But events are never received and my test always passes where it should fail. How can I configure my test to catch the events? Here is my test method:

```
@Test
public void testCallback() throws Exception {

    FunctionalTestComponent ftc = getFunctionalTestComponent("test");
    ftc.setEventCallback(new EventCallback()
    {
       public void eventReceived(MuleEventContext context, Object component)
           throws Exception
       {
             assertTrue(false);
             System.out.println("Thanks for calling me back");
       }
     });

     MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();
     MuleMessage reply = client.send("vm://test", TEST_MESSAGE, null, 5000);
}
```

The config is just 2 flows with a test:component in the second flow which is referenced by the vm://test flow.

The only way I could get it to work was by using a latch and an `AtomicReference` to save the MuleMessage so I can run assertions after the `muleClient.send`.

```
FunctionalTestComponent ftc = getFunctionalTestComponent("test");

      final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
      final AtomicReference<MuleMessage> message = new AtomicReference<MuleMessage>();

      EventCallback callback = new EventCallback() {
         public void eventReceived(MuleEventContext context, Object component)
               throws Exception {
            if (1 == latch.getCount()) {
               message.set(context.getMessage());
               System.out.println("1111");
               latch.countDown();
            }
         }
      };

      ftc.setEventCallback(callback);
      MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();
      client.send("vm://test", TEST_MESSAGE, null);
      latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      MuleMessage msg = (MuleMessage) message.get();
```

Comment: Is the second flow called asynchronously?

Comment: No. It's just a synchronous flow with a http inbound endpoint followed by a test:component

Comment: Then I don't get it, I use similar code as yours all the time, and it works fine, `eventReceived` gets called.

Comment: I know it's strange. If I add an assertion in the eventRecieved it just doesnt work as expected. I have updated my answer to show how I have managed to get it to work. But I have had to use a Latch and an AtomicReference to store the MuleMessage so I can run assertions after the muleClient.send(... Do you think this could be a timing thing? As my test ends with muleClient.send(... then the test is finishing before the events are recieved?

Comment: No the problem is that assertions in the event have strictly no effect to the test itself, as they are run by a Mule thread not the test thread. Using latches/atomic refs is a common pattern to bring messages back to the test thread, you did well. Note that Mule has a Latch helper class that's just a CountDownLatch(1): http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/util/concurrent/Latch.html